# AngularJS Ionic $http request to API maintain authentication data

Tags: android, angularjs, caching, ionic-framework, basic-authentication

I'm writing Ionic/Cordova-based application which requires usage of external API where authentication data must be provided (via http-basic header).

The problem is that the application maintains the authorization (after providing correct credentials) and I am not able to logout (force the application to block access to the API).

HTTP authentication validation mechanism:

```
var validateCredentials = function(user, password, callback) {

    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://server.host.com/api/check?Accept=application/json',
         headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(user + ':' + password)
         }
    };

    $http(req).success(function(data) {
        callback(true);
    }).error(function(error) {
        callback(false);
    });
}
```

My use case:

1) I am providing wrong credentials to the method and recieve 401 (which is good):

[image]

2) Then I provide correct credentials and recieve 200 OK (which is also good):

[image]

3) And finally, if I provide the wrong credentials one more time the API is still working (200 instead of 401):

[image]

As a result, I cannot logout from my application and moreover - I cannot login to different user!

I've tried to clear caches, ionic history and webview cache with https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache but still no success. The only option to clear the session/authentication data is Andoird OS Settings/Application/Clear App Data.

And finally - there are no cookies or session variables in the context of the application (at least according to Chrome Developper console running in debug mode with my device).

Any hints appreciated!